# Why is this now giving me an UnboundedLocalError?

Tags: python-3.x

This was working and now has stopped and is giving me an error I can't see what's wrong with it?

```
def grade(R):
    x = str(R)
    if 'Practitioner' in x:
        y = x.replace('Practitioner', ' ')
    elif 'P' in x:
        y = x.replace('P', ' ')
    elif 'p' in x:
        y = x.replace('p', ' ')
    elif 'Graduate' in x:
        y = x.replace('Graduate', ' ')
    elif 'G' in x:
        y =x.replace('G', ' ')
    elif 'g' in x:
        y = x.replace('g', ' ')

    y = int(y)
    g = inf.number_to_words(y)
    return (g)
```

Full Script

```
import datetime
import os
from random import choice
from string import digits
import subprocess
import inflect
import pandas as pd
import reportlab
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
# import xlrd
from reportlab.lib.units import mm

# set inflect
inf = inflect.engine()

# set fonts
folder = os.path.dirname(reportlab.__file__) + os.sep + 'fonts'
ttfFile_b = os.path.join(folder, 'VeraBd.ttf')
ttfFile_r = os.path.join(folder, 'Vera.ttf')
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("VeraBd", ttfFile_b))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("Vera", ttfFile_r))

# Set date usage stuff

w = datetime.datetime.now()
d = datetime.date.today()
m = d.month
y = d.year + 1
p = str(w.hour) + '-' + str(w.minute) + '_' + str(w.second)
end_date = str(m) + '/' + str(y)


def grade(R):
    x = str(R)
    if 'Practitioner' in x:
        y = x.replace('Practitioner', ' ')
    elif 'P' in x:
        y = x.replace('P', ' ')
    elif 'p' in x:
        y = x.replace('p', ' ')
    elif 'Graduate' in x:
        y = x.replace('Graduate', ' ')
    elif 'G' in x:
        y =x.replace('G', ' ')
    elif 'g' in x:
        y = x.replace('g', ' ')

    y = int(y)
    g = inf.number_to_words(y)
    return (g)


def level(R):
    x = str(R)
    y = x.replace('Practitioner', ' ')
    int(y)
    g = inf.number_to_words(y)
    return (g)


# Routine to get location
def location(L):
    x = str(L)
    if 'London' in x:
        l = str("London")
    elif 'Stratford' in x:
        l = str("Stratford Upon Avon")
    elif 'Bristol' in x:
        l = str("Bristol")
    elif 'Penrith' in x:
        l = str("Penrith")
    else:
        l = str("United Kingdom")

    return (l)


# Get date
def when(D):
    dt = D.strftime('%d %B %Y')

    d = str(dt)

    return (d)


# get random diploma number
def dip():
    x = ''.join(choice(digits) for i in range(6))
    k = str(x)
    return (k)


def p_certs(df):
# set PDF file name and canvas size
#  file_location = 'C:\Users\Suely\Desktop\Ouput_PDF\'
# Set date usage stuff

    w = datetime.datetime.now()
    d = datetime.date.today()
    m = d.month
    y = d.year + 1
    p = str(w.hour) + '-' + str(w.minute) + '_' + str(w.second)
    # end_date = str(m) + '/' + str(y)

    file_name = 'CERTIFICATES_' + str(d) + '_' + str(p) + '.pdf'
    c = canvas.Canvas(file_name, pagesize=(210 * mm, 297 * mm))
        # 1mm = 0.35277777 pt


    # draw each page
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # D = str(row['Date'])
        # R = row['Grading Level (National Grading)']
        # L = row['Select Grading Event']
        # g = location(L)

        # A = row['Grading Committee']
        # I = row['Instructor']
        g = row['Location']
        fn = str.strip(row['First Name'])
        ln = str.strip(row['Last Name'])
        f = row['Grade']
        # r = row['Grade']
        r = grade(f)
        # d = str('11 August 2018')
        # d = when(D)
        d = str(row['Date'])
        N = fn + ' ' + ln
        # N = row['First Name'] + ' ' + row['Last Name']
        # N = row['First Name'] + row['Last Name']
        k = dip()
        #k2 = str('KMG-UK -') + str(k)
        k2 = row['Diploma Number']

        # Draw Name
        c.setFont('VeraBd', 24, leading=None)
        c.drawCentredString(297.63786, 160 * mm, str.title(N))

        # Draw Grade
        c.setFont('VeraBd', 18, leading=None)
        c.drawCentredString(110 * mm, 130 * mm, str.upper(r))

        # Draw Place
        c.setFont('VeraBd', 14, leading=None)
        # c.drawCentredString(297.63786, 261.8581643, str.title(g))
        c.drawCentredString(105 * mm, 91 * mm, str.upper(g))

        # Draw Date
        c.setFont('VeraBd', 14, leading=None)
        # c.drawCentredString(297.63786, 236.3463527, str.title(d))
        c.drawCentredString(105 * mm, 81 * mm, str(d))

        # Draw Diploma number
        c.setFont('VeraBd', 11, leading=None)
        c.drawCentredString(105 * mm, 71 * mm, str.upper(k2))
        c.showPage()

        # Draw Administration & Instructor
        # c.setFont('VeraBd', 12, leading=None)
        # c.drawCentredString(60*mm, 25*mm, str.upper(I))
        # c.setFont('VeraBd', 12, leading=None)
        # c.drawCentredString(105*mm, 25*mm, str.upper(A))

    c.save()
    subprocess.Popen([file_name], shell=True)

# set data file
data_location = '007. P1_P2 Data Sheet.csv'
file_name2 = '007. P1_P2 Data Sheet.xlsx'

# read dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(data_location, encoding='latin1', na_values=['nan'], keep_default_na=False)

# df = pd.read_excel(file_name2, 'Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])

p_certs(df)
```

The Error
C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/00000001 Licence Print/P certs/002 P1 Certificates/Certificatea.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/00000001 Licence Print/P certs/002 P1 Certificates/Certificatea.py", line 179, in 
    p_certs(df)
  File "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/00000001 Licence Print/P certs/002 P1 Certificates/Certificatea.py", line 127, in p_certs
    r = grade(f)
  File "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/00000001 Licence Print/P certs/002 P1 Certificates/Certificatea.py", line 50, in grade
    y = int(y)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What's the exact error? `y` won't be set unless one of the conditions is true. What are you expecting `y` to be if they're all false?

Comment: We cannot run this code without inputs. Do you mind providing them?

Comment: I've added the whole script the error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/00000001 Licence Print/P certs/002 P1 Certificates/Certificatea.py", line 179, in <module>
    p_certs(df)
  File "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/00000001 Licence Print/P certs/002 P1 Certificates/Certificatea.py", line 127, in p_certs
    r = grade(f)
  File "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/00000001 Licence Print/P certs/002 P1 Certificates/Certificatea.py", line 50, in grade
    y = int(y)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local variable `y` would not be initialized before its usage in the statement `y = int(y)` if none of the `if` and `elif` conditions before it are met.

You can assign to `y` a default value in an `else` clause instead:

```
def grade(R):
    x = str(R)
    if 'Practitioner' in x:
        y = x.replace('Practitioner', ' ')
    elif 'P' in x:
        y = x.replace('P', ' ')
    elif 'p' in x:
        y = x.replace('p', ' ')
    elif 'Graduate' in x:
        y = x.replace('Graduate', ' ')
    elif 'G' in x:
        y =x.replace('G', ' ')
    elif 'g' in x:
        y = x.replace('g', ' ')
    else:
        y = '0'

    y = int(y)
    g = inf.number_to_words(y)
    return (g)
```

Or you can try fixing your input data to ensure that the argument `R` would always result in satisfying one of the conditions in the `if` and `elif` clauses.